# Adding a BoardView extends View class to a linearlayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How do I add a view to LinearLayout? I have a class named BoardView that extends View, and I want to add it to a LinearLayout. My code looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  board = new Board();
  boardView = new BoardView(this, board);
  board.addObserver(boardView);
  setContentView(boardView);
}
```

and I tried something like this:

```
LinearLayout boardgame = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.boardgame);
linBoardGame.addView(boardview);
setContentView(boardgame);
```

unfortunately this returns a NullPointerException.
same exception for adding

```
<com.example.abc.def.BoardView  
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

to game_activity.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add view inside a `ViewGroup` you first have to have a `ViewGroup` in Activity.
So have a `ViewGroup` in Activity's xml .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/boardgame"
>



</LinearLayout>
```

Then add the view to `ViewGroup`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actity_layout);
    board = new Board();
    boardView = new BoardView(this, board);
    board.addObserver(boardView);
    LinearLayout boardgame = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.boardgame);
    linBoardGame.addView(boardview);
}
```